# Feature stapling to delete the folder in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, feature-stapling

My requirement is whenever particular My Site is created default folder will appear, I don't want that default folder, so need to create a feature stapling on activated method whenever my site creation "default " folder should be deleted.

Can anyone tell me any sample code for folder deletion using feature stapling

Comment: why u dont need default folder ?

Comment: Quit asking the same question in slightly differing fashion, update you original question if you are looking for PowerShell or feature stapling ideas.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sharepointologic.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/branding-sharepoint-2013-my-sites-with.html?_sm_au_=iQV55f5ZNBFSF1H6) is an explanation for the feature stapling. The example explains how to set the master page. In the feature event receiver code you can write the logic to delete the folder. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karthick/archive/2006/04/06/570388.aspx) is a sample code to delete a folder in sharepoint document library programmatically.